# how to close a tcp connection if FIN/ACK doesn't get a ACK response?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

in a tcp program written in Linux C
I want to close a tcp connectin
I used `close(sockfd)`
I notice this function will initiate a FIN/ACK packet to the other peer
but if the other peer doesn't respond an ACK due to network problem or tcp sequnce number inconsistency(e.g the tcp stack of the other peer crashes)
then it seems the tcp connection can't be closed
it will always be in FIN_WAIT1  status

how to deal with this?
how to close the tcp connection in such cases?

Comment: Then the closing part will try again sending `FIN`, and again a couple of more times, until it finally times out and `close` returns with an error.

Comment: it seems to me `close()` is not in blocking style, and so the error can't be returned after it is called. how to get the error?

Comment: @user1944267 Is the socket blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: so you mean the behavior of `close()` depends on whether the socket is blocking or not, if it is not, `close()` will not return -1?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but it's the kind of behavior I would expect from a non-blocking socket, that `close` would return immediately.

Comment: close() is asynchronous in either blocking or non-blocking mode, unless you have set a linger timeout, in which case it either blocks for up to the timeout or (presumably) sets errno = EAGAIN if required.

Answer (score -1):

By default, this is transparently handled by the TCP implementation according to system-wide configuration parameters which are system-dependent.

This can be overridden by setting the `SO_LINGER` socket option using `setsockopt()`, in which case the call to `close()` blocks until the specified timeout is reached.

Edit: I should add that most of the time using SO_LINGER is only worth the hassle if the goal is to add some error handling such as logging an error message stating that possibly some data was not received by the other end.

Comment: SO_LINGER has nothing do with it. It causes the `close()` to block until the pending data and the outgoing FIN have been flushed, *or* until the *specified* timeout supplied to `setsockopt()` is reached, not the 'configured timeout', and it doesn't require the FIN to be ACK'd.

Comment: You are right in that I should have written "specified" and not "configured". But... you have down-voted this answer because of such a simple wording issue? You should know by now that there is an `edit` link under every answer for cases such as this one. **And by the way, it seems to me that not waiting for an ACK any longer is exactly what the OP wants to do.**

Answer (score -2):

TCP deals with it. You don't have to deal with it. You can't deal with it.

Comment: **This is factually false.** There are at least two ways one can deals with this: by tuning the TCP stack so that the TCP session will timeout sooner or at the application level by using `setsockopt()` with `SO_LINGER`. **An answer being factually false is the reason why you should down-vote it.**

Comment: @ErwanLegrand SO_LINGER does not deal with this case. It does not provide a way to escape from the FIN_WAIT_1 state. The OP's question is about how to close the connection in such cases, and the answer remains that you can't, other than via the non-programming solution of tuning the TCP stack, which is off-topic here.